# Return the most recent record only if a query results in records having the same value in a given column

Tags: sql

If my query is

```
SELECT * FROM EventLog WHERE Role LIKE %Admin%
```

And the query resulted in 3 records with Name column value "John" and 4 records with Name column value "Bob",

I would want it to only show me one Bob and one John result, and have the single result it includes for each name be the one with the latest date in the Date column (for that name)

Basically, remove duplicate Name results and just show the one with the most recent date for that name.

Comment: There are multiple ways to write the required query. One of the way is using [Row_Number](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-row_number-function/). Check that if it helps you.

Comment: You can use Distinct in your query to remove duplication of rows for more info, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Comment: State the name and version of your database system. That query you posted has a syntax error btw

Comment: @MayurAsodariya please don't jump straight to "getting duplicates? Smash a DISTINCT in there to solve the problem" - it's better to solve the problem that causes the duplicates, not cause them and take them out afterwards. Too many lazy SQL devs get duplicates and think the answer is to use DISTINCT; it very seldom is

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a correlated sub-query to get the most recent record for each name - here is a similar solution for getting the most expensive product for each supplier from a table of products:

```
SELECT P1.* FROM [Products] AS P1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SupplierID, MAX(Price) AS MaxPrice FROM [Products] GROUP BY SupplierID
) AS P2 ON (P1.SupplierID = P2.SupplierID AND P1.Price = P2.MaxPrice)
```

I tested this at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in  but I don't have a database locally to be able to setup an exact example for your EventLog table, but the principle is the same.  You will need to get the MAX(Date) and GROUP BY Name.

Comment: Does the p1 and p2 work with any db? I know I would need to change the column names just wondering how to use this as a template

Comment: I think so - I believe the syntax for table aliasing is similar for most ANSI-SQL databases. It will work for SQL Server if that is what you are using.

Comment: "The answer is" should say "One option is"; there are many ways to skin this cat. This way can still cause repeat results